# Radio Button in Layer List Widget Instead of Eye Icon

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, widget

I'm using `portalItem` to display a web map in a web page and the Layer List widget to control the layer display. I want to show one layer at a time using radio buttons, instead of having to click on the eyes to turn off one layer and turn on another.

[image: Layer List widget]

Does ArcGIS API for JavaScript have the option? I'm using version 4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Layer List can show radio buttons (see [this example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=widgets-layerlist)), but this is something that's built into a web scene designer, where you can change the group type from CheckBox to Radio. See this [scene](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=37314d6f358248a3830113a6ae883ac7) as an example. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be an option in a web map

Comment: @kenbujia It seems like to be this case in web map. Looks like putting feature layers into group layer is the only way to have the radio button.

Comment: Correct.  The radio buttons (aka visibilityMode=exclusive) is a feature of a group layer. Web map specification doesn't yet support group layers (but WebScene specification and JSAPI 4 does).
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GroupLayer.html